# How to add an icon beside all the series in an legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to add a favicon beside all the series data objects in the legend of my highcharts pie chart but I'm having no luck. I've searched around for a few hours but it seems like all of the examples are not quite right. I want it to look like the image below

[image]

I though adding the icon to the series data and defining it in the legends labelFormatter like this:

```
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  floating: true,
  borderWidth: 0,
  align: 'right',
  layout: 'vertical',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  itemMarginTop: 20,
  itemMarginBottom: 20,
  labelFormatter: function() {
    return '<span style="font-weight: normal;">' + this.name + ' </span> <span style:"font-weight: normal;"><b>€' + this.y + '<br/></span>';
  }
},

   series: [{
  name: 'Transactions',
  data: [{
    name: 'Carrots',
    y: 7450.00,
    icon: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }, {
    name: 'Apples',
    y: 435.00,
    icon: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }, {
    name: 'Oranges',
    y: 300.87,
    icon: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }, {
    name: 'Lemons',
    y: 45.67,
    icon: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }, {
    name: 'Limes',
    y: 42.45,
    icon: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }],
```

would work the best but still no luck.
Can anybody please enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong? The whole code is here http://jsfiddle.net/tobitobetoby/1fqvzpdn/6/

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your legend, you can enable HTML with the `useHTML` flag.  I also didn't see anywhere in your code where you were adding the image, so I added an image tag to the labelFormatter.

```
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  floating: true,
  borderWidth: 0,
  align: 'right',
  layout: 'vertical',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  itemMarginTop: 20,
  itemMarginBottom: 20,
  useHTML: true,
  labelFormatter: function() {
    return '<span style="font-weight: normal;">' + this.name + ' </span> <span style:"font-weight: normal;"><b>€' + this.y + '<br/><image src="' + this.icon +'" /></span>';
  }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/1fqvzpdn/8/

Comment: This is brilliant Barbara! Thank you! I've decided to add the icon before the series name but I'm being thrown errors. Do you know why this is not working? Thank you again! return '<image src="' + this.icon +'" /><span style="font-weight: normal;">' + this.name + ' </span> <span style:"font-weight: normal;"><b>€' + this.y + '<br/></span>';

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/1fqvzpdn/11/